# Big difference in time of uploading file between AWS-console in browser and AmazonSDK for java

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am writing simple uploader for amazon s3 and found some issue. If i try upload file(for example tulips.jpg) to bucket from aws-console i do it by 2-3 seconds, but if i try it in my uploader time is ~30sec. this is my uploader function

```
public class AWSfunctions implements Runnable {
TransferManager tx;
File file;

AWSfunctions(File file) throws IOException {
    Config conf;
    String AccessKeyId;
    String SecretKey;
    AWSCredentials credentials;
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
    conf = ConfigFactory.load();
    AccessKeyId = conf.getString("AWSCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId");
    SecretKey = conf.getString("AWSCredentials.AWSSecretKey");
    credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKeyId, SecretKey);

    this.tx = new TransferManager(credentials);
    this.file = file;
    System.out.println("thread get file" + this.file.getName());
}

public void sendFile() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("test-for-est", String.valueOf(rnd.nextInt()) + ".jpg", file);
    long lBegin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Upload myUpload = tx.upload(request);
    try {
        myUpload.waitForCompletion();
        file.delete();
        long lEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lDelta = lEnd - lBegin;
        System.out.println("TA DA DAM!" + lDelta);
    } catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
        amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        this.sendFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then i try use multipart upload in many examples from internet forums or amazon documentation but nothing help. i want know how it work, why uploading from aws-console is too fast. sorry for my bad english, i hope that i will find answer with your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a good point which you have identified. Actually speaking the AWS Console works at the Internet Scale more precisely AWS Scale; over that S3 is in top among list of AWS Service used; so obviously there would be so many optimizations,  improvements, massive scale which has been setup to accomplish the upload from the AWS Console.

It is not a straight forward Apple to Apple Comparison to compare AWS Console and custom SDK Application to perform the same operation.

The better way to approach the problem would be to identify how you improve the performance using Java, Your Code etc. There are several things which affect / effect the performance like your OS, H/W, JDK Version, AWS SDK, Your Code etc.

Fundamentally speaking AWS Console is a Web Application and your application is Console Application ( or an app running from your desktop ). They are 2 totally different species all together.

The analogy which I can tell you is the speed of sending an email may be faster in the Outlook.com - Web Client rather than your mail being sent from your Outlook Application running in your desktop.

Comment: oh...thank you, but i do all how it show in docks. step by step. i don`t believe that is ok, when ~800kb upload for ~40sec

Comment: this explanation does not explain why it takes 40 secs for 800kb instead ... when using the console, your browser does the connection.  When running your app, the JVM is making the connection.  Assuming the two run from the same machine and the same network (to double check) : is your browser configured to connect through a proxy or other netwrok device ?  Or so is your JVM ?

Comment: @sebsto , i have a netty server and speed of upload not corellation with number of connect. so, i change bucket place from tokio to ireland and get ~11sec for simple jpeg. if i right understand information in your profile, you are work with/in amazon, and i want know what is normal speed as usually, please